# Authenticate against Active Directory in .NET Core 1.0 application?

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

With the recent release of .NET Core 1.0, we're in the process of migrating our RC1 applications to the final release. The only piece we can't seem to figure out is how to integrate Active Directory authentication.

Previously in the RC1 applications, we had used the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement library to handle the LDAP authorization queries. However, we can no longer mix this library with .NET Core v1.

Generally, what is the best way to integrate Active Directory authentication into our applications using the libraries available for use in the .NET Core framework? IdentityServer, some other third party service like Auth0 or something else?

Comment: See this issue on github.  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089  This one might also help you.  https://github.com/jesblit/ASPNET5-FormAuthenticationLDAP/issues/3

Comment: FWIW, group/name based Active Directory auth currently works, but there are other features still missing - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746645/aspnet-5-mvc6-windows-auth-roles-authorize-attribute/38274506#38274506

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Novell.LDAP library has been [ported](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard) to .NET Core you can find it in [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/). There are numerous [samples](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/tree/master/original_samples) available, including a verify password [sample](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/blob/master/original_samples/Samples/VerifyPassword.cs).

Comment: Just FYI those samples are also "ported", & the options are cryptic - it was easier to get this lib up & running using the source C# docs [directly from Novell](https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/)

Comment: unfortunately, I can´t use Novel.LDAP because is necessary authentication to bind e query ldap and this permission is restricted in my company...

Answer (score 8):

Best is subjective, really there's only one way right now, given the missing DirectoryServices namespace (which is planning for 1.1) - federation.

You'd have to install [ADFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx), and expose it to the internet. Then you configure it to act as an OAuth2 endpoint, and use the generic OAuth middleware to redirect logins to your ADFS server. You could also install the latest ADFS beta, which needs the latest Windows Server beta, and use OpenID Connect, but that's a lot of beta risks you may not find acceptable.

Or, if you just want the latest MVC pieces, run it on .NET Desktop, where you have full access to the directory services namespace.

Comment: I'm having troubles setting up ADFS & OAuth2. Is there any documentation or workshop files on how to do this with AspNetCore packages & framework 1.0.*?

Answer (score 3):

The System.DirectoryServices namespace is currently being implemented in .NET Core, work is ongoing.
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089

Comment: Seems completed 28 days ago. I will maybe give it a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just want to say that they just issued a pre-release of the Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility  which contains the System.DirectoryServices components needed to integrating with Active Directory

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/2.0.0-preview1-25914-04