# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, directoryservices

Is there any hope that this namespace will be port to .net core?

(I am having much trouble utilizing 3rd party libraries for LDAP authentication)

I am specifically asking IF and WHEN will System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace be available, so my question is not duplicate to :

[Authenticate against Active Directory in .NET Core 1.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084421/authenticate-against-active-directory-in-net-core-1-0-application)

(which is asking generally for alternatives to the namespace)

**Update Jan-2018**
This question is still valid ESPECIALLY for programmers that need to port code to .net Core and seek for out-of-the-box support of the namespace System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.

It may be very usefull to many programmers that the above is actually doable now with the Core 2.1 release and through the [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/). This pack incorporates the DirectoryServices namespaces needed.

**BUT beware that it can actually work when running on Windows Platform!**

Comment: My question is not duplicate of the one mentioned about authentication with ldap. I am specifically asking about a certain namespace of the directory services. The other one is more general.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this issue on github:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089

At the moment, it is not yet available. It sounds like work has been done to get it up and running in Netstandard on windows, but isn't available yet. At the end of the thread, karelz mentions he might be publishing it to the preview MyGet branch.